# Prometheus - Aggregate and relabel by regex

Tags: prometheus, promql

I currently have the following Promql query which allow me to query the memory used by each of my K8S pods:

`sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes{image!="",name=~"^k8s_.*"}) by (pod_name)`

The pod's name is followed by a hash defined by K8S:

```
weave-net-kxpxc
weave-net-jjkki
weave-net-asdkk
```

Which all belongs to the same app: `weave-net`

What I would like is to aggregate the memory of all pods which belongs to the same app.

So, the query would sum the memory of all `weave-net` pods and place the result in an app called `weave`. Such as the result would be:

```
{pod_name="weave-net"}            10
```

instead of

```
{pod_name="weave-net-kxpxc"}       5
{pod_name="weave-net-jjkki"}       3
{pod_name="weave-net-asdkk"}       2
```

Is it even possible to do so, and if yes, how ?

Comment: I have the exact same problem and didn't find a solution do do this in this stage (I guess it is not possible). However, It is possible to add an additional label and use the regex in the relabel config of prometheus to get a label to group. If that is a possible solution for you, I can post an answer how to do this.

Comment: Hi @ThomasBöhm! Would be happy to see your solution indeed. Personally, I just went to write a Python script that filter out results based on regex.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use [label_replace](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace)

```
sum(label_replace(container_memory_working_set_bytes{image!="",name=~"^k8s_.*"}, "pod_set", "$1", "pod_name", "(.*)-.{5}")) by (pod_set)
```

You will be including a new label (`pod_set`) that matches the first group ($1) from matching the regex over the `pod_name` label. Then you sum over the new label `pod_set`.

[Edited]

Comment: How to do this over a range? say 10 minutes average https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60783916/label-replace-over-a-range-vector-in-prometheus

Comment: Thanks for the solution , what is this `"(.*)-.{5}"` part about ?

Answer (score 4):

Iván's answer is spot on. `label_replace` doesn't work for range vectors (and it [seems likely](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/2671) to stay that way), but there's [a workaround](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/2671#issuecomment-654779295) using subqueries:

```
sum( 
  rate(
    label_replace(
      container_memory_working_set_bytes{image!="",name=~"^k8s_.*"}, 
      "pod_set", 
      "$1", 
      "pod_name", 
      "(.*)-.{5}"
    )[5m:] <-- it's the trailing colon here that makes it work
  )
) by (pod_set)
```

Comment: It is better just swapping `rate` with `label_replace` in the query. This eliminates the need to use subqueries and improves query performance and accuracy in general case.