# Label replace over a range vector in Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, promql

I want to find the sum number of alerts for all the pods starting with "sendsms" over 10minutes.

I am able to do use [label_replace()](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace) to do this on the instant vector. But when i want to do this for over 10 minutes data, it cannot work as label_replace only works on instant vector.

Explaining the problem with an example:

```
ALERTS{alertname="CPUThrottlingHigh",pod="sendsms-dbed"} 10
ALERTS{alertname="CPUThrottlingHigh",pod="sendsms-ebed"} 20
ALERTS{alertname="CPUThrottlingHigh",pod="sendsms-fbed"} 30
```

```
ALERTS{alertname="CPUThrottlingHigh",pod="sendmail-gbed"} 60
ALERTS{alertname="CPUThrottlingHigh",pod="sendmail-hbed"} 70
ALERTS{alertname="CPUThrottlingHigh",pod="sendmail-ibed"} 80
```

Using label replace i can add a new label using the REGEX and then i can group it and get the results.

`label_replace(ALERTS{alertname="CPUThrottlingHigh", "podname", "$1", "pod", "([a-z-A-Z]+)-.*")`

```
ALERTS{alertname="CPUThrottlingHigh",pod="sendsms-dbed", podname="sendsms"} 10
ALERTS{alertname="CPUThrottlingHigh",pod="sendsms-dbed", podname="sendsms"} 10
```

**How to do this for ALERTS in 10 minutes and calculate the sum?**

I want some result like this for last 10 minutes

```
ALERTS{alertname="CPUThrottlingHigh",podname="sendsms"} 60
ALERTS{alertname="CPUThrottlingHigh",podname="sendmail"} 210
```

**Objective**: Find the pods which are creating maximum no of alerts in last 1 week.

Comment: Why not just use a regex selector?

Comment: The pod name has a uuid in it. And i want to get the data for all pods, not just sendsms (also from sendmail, in the same query). It does not look it is possible to do that with only regex selector. Can you share an example query if you see it is as possible?

Comment: pod=~”(sendsms|sendmail)-.*”

Comment: i want to get the data for all the pods not just sendsms. let me edit the question.

Comment: there are like 1000 pods like this. Not just these two. My aim is to find the pods generating the maximum no of alerts.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614030/prometheus-aggregate-and-relabel-by-regex

Answer (score 9):

I was able to solve this problem by doing label_replace after doing the sum

**Query**

```
sort_desc(
  sum by (pod_set) (
    label_replace(
      sort_desc(
        sum by (namespace, pod) (
          avg_over_time(
            ALERTS{
              alertname=~"(KubeDeploymentReplicasMismatch|KubePodNotReady|KubePodCrashLooping|KubeJobFailed)",
              alertstate="firing"
            }[1w]
          )
        )
      ), "pod_set", "$1", "pod", "([a-z-A-Z]+)-.*"
    )
  )
)
```

**Result**

```
{pod_set="sendsms"} 62
{pod_set="emailspreprocessor"}  32
{pod_set="sendmail"}    21
```